# Selected Item in a WPF Combobox, bound with a dictionary, shows full object, not just the value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, combobox

Using WPF, I'm binding a ComboBox to a dictionary. The items display correctly, and have the correct value for each. However, when an item is selected, the SelectedItem displays the entire dictionary object, and not just the value.

xaml code:

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox"/>
```

c# code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> CombBoxItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
CombBoxItems.Add("aaa", "I am AAA");
CombBoxItems.Add("bbb", "I am BBB");
CombBoxItems.Add("ccc", "I am CCC");
CombBoxItems.Add("ddd", "I am DDD");
CombBoxItems.Add("eee", "I am EEE");
CombBoxItems.Add("fff", "I am FFF");


MyComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
MyComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";

MyComboBox.ItemsSource = CombBoxItems;
```

It displays like this once an item is selected:

[image: ComboBox Sample]

The selected item should display only the text, like the items themselves do.

I've tried different combinations of the SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath, both inline and in code, but I can't seem to find the right combination for the selected text.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. Is there anything else missing? Probably shouldn't matter for this but why aren't you using MVVM?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me as you expected. However, I doubt something. Can you see if you have some default style for the combobox in your application?